# Why doesn't Python multiprocessing work on my PC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-multiprocessing

So since I have a 16 core CPU I wanted to try multiprocessing Python code with this script:

```
import time

NUMBERS = 50000, 50001, 50002, 50003, 50004, 50005, 50006, 50007, 50008, 50009, 50010, 50011, 50012, 50013, 50014, 50015

def factorial(n):
    print(f"start: factorial {n}")
    f = 1 
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        f*=i
    print(f"done: factorial {n}")
    return f


import multiprocessing as mp

t0 = time.time()
with mp.Pool() as pool: 
    result = pool.map(factorial, NUMBERS)
t1 = time.time()
print(f"Excecution took {t1-t0:.4f}")
```

But when I execute the cell in the Jupyter distribution of Anaconda it doesn't output anything and it doesn't stop as well.

Platform information:

CPU: i9 9900K

OS: Windows 10 Pro (10.0 Build 18362)

Anaconda Version: 1.9.7

Python 3.7.4

Jupyter is started separately from Windows Powershell in its special directory with the command

```
Jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Read the documentation of [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). You need the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guardian.

Comment: I would try installing Anaconda again and for starters look in the command window for the errors from where u launched the notebook. Also add some platform information to your question.

Comment: Here is the example code running without the  if __name__ == '__main__' : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EBs1BDvuzk